# correlated subquery cannot have TOP or ORDER BY

Tags: hana

Need to migrate from SQL to SAP HANA. I need CTE equivalent in HANA.

Using Top 1 and inner join in migration query from SQL to SAP HANA
tried using LIMIT but got error.

> error correlated subquery cannot have TOP or ORDER BY

```
with cte As ( select SLART,upper(STEXT) as STEXT , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by upper(STEXT) 
    order by upper(STEXT) ASC ) as number 
    FROM table1 
    WHERE SLART LIKE 'X%' AND SPRSL='E' AND MANDT=client AND SLART != 'X0') 
select SLART,upper(substring(STEXT,1,1))+ lower(substring(STEXT,2,len(STEXT)) ) as 'STEXT' 
    from cte where number = 1 
    ORDER BY STEXT ASC
```

Comment: tried with using limit but fail with Where condition and inner join

Comment: also tried with Row_number but dont know how to use exactly as new to HANA

Comment: can yo maybe post an example what you are trying to do

Comment: with cte As (
select SLART,upper(STEXT) as STEXT , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by upper(STEXT) order by upper(STEXT) ASC ) as number FROM 
table1 WHERE SLART LIKE 'X%' AND SPRSL='E' AND MANDT=client AND SLART != 'X0') 
select SLART,upper(substring(STEXT,1,1))+ lower(substring(STEXT,2,len(STEXT))
) 
 as 'STEXT' from cte where number = 1 ORDER BY STEXT ASC                                Need to migrate from SQL to SAP HANA  I need CTE equavalent in HANA

Comment: Please update your question instead of putting the SQL code into the comment section.

Comment: correlated query in SAP HANA using TOP1 gives erro in innner join and where condition.

Comment: SQL to SAP HANA conversion instead of TOP you should use is Distinct MAX.